# Not able to use My Class library in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

I am using Visual Studio 2017. I have a solution and in that solution I have 2 projects. One project is a library I made. This library is using Target Framework .Net Standard 1.6 and Output type: Class Library. The other project is a Windows Application using Target Framework: .Net Framework 4.6.1 and output type: Windows Application.

I added my class library to my windows application and the reference is in the Reference section, but when I try to use a class from the library, it cannot find it. Also I tried adding the "Using MyLibrary" and it still cannot find the reference. What else can I do?

Comment: Are you using .NET Core SDK 2.0?

Comment: There actually are some Bugs in VisualStudio, Resharper and all the tooling with .NET Standard <-> .NET Framework references. Does it build, when you manually add the using? Also if you are using Resharper update to the newest EAP version, that should fix most issues

Comment: Have you tried to clean and build the solution and try it again?

Comment: What exact version of Visual Studio do you have? Is it less than 15.3.1?

Comment: @Isma I'm using Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms(1.1.0),

Comment: @TobiasTheel I am not using Resharper

Comment: @WillyDavidJr I have tried building and rebuilding, and closing visual studio

Comment: @TobiasTheel I am using Version 15.3.2

Comment: @KostyaK Version 15.3.2

Comment: I tried removing the other 2 references I had: Dapper and BCrypt.Net and still nothing.

Comment: Do you have older versions of VS installed?

Comment: are the classes in the library project public, with public methods?

Comment: Try installing version 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why but the whole solution must had been corrupted or something. So I remade a whole new solution and created the projects again and copied all my files over and it worked. Not sure what the whole problem was but it is now working.